# Faster calculation of whether an unlikely event occurs, in Python

Tags: python, random, simulation

I have a simulation in which I need to check over and over if an unlikely event occurs.

If the odds of the event are 1 in n, this is what my code looks like:

```
if random.randint(1,int(n)) == 1:
    do_stuff
```

That is, randomly generate an integer from 1 to n, and check if it is 1 (could pick any value in the range).

I have a suspicion that this may be slow. Does there look like an obvious way to do this differently to anyone?

Comment: "I have a suspicion that this may be slow" is not a good reason to start micro-optimizing. "My program is too slow, and I profiled and found that `randint` is taking 23% of the total time" is a good reason to start micro-optimizing.

Comment: Is this a time-based simulation, and if so, are you doing event scheduling?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm should have tried this before asking the question, but I just found that this:

```
if numpy.random.randint(1,int(n)) == 1:
    do_stuff
```

is two or three times faster. Of course I'm still interested to see if there's an even better way.

Comment: Just an idea... generate at once a vector with all the random ints you are going to use in the simulation, this approach could be faster than repeatedly calling the random number generator

Comment: @me ps: how much time is spent on the simulation with respect to generating the random integers?